# Render multi-level HTML menu from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops, dom

I want to render a menu and subcategories from JSON.

Now I am able to display the menu, but I don't understand how I can further display the subcategories.

At the end of the sub-menu should be next to the menu, but this is not necessary, the main thing for me is to understand the principle of how to display this most flexibly.

The problem with the current code is that in the JSON there are 2 children, but when I display them, they are all added to one link. I want that if the object has children, each receives its own link and is displayed.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data.json')
.then(function (response) {
    const posts = response.data;

    console.log(posts.length);

    posts.forEach((elem) => {

        let nav = document.querySelector('.nav-inner'),
            link = document.createElement('a');

        link.className = 'nav-inner__link';
        link.setAttribute('href', '/' + elem.url);

        link.append(elem.title);

        nav.appendChild(link);


        if (elem.childred !== 0) {

            let i = elem.childrens,
                menu = document.querySelector('.menu'),
                menuLink = document.createElement('a');
                menuLink.className = 'menu__link';

            i.forEach((elem) => {
                console.log('sub-menu-link -' + elem.title);

                menuLink.setAttribute('href', '/' + elem.url);
                menuLink.append(elem.name);
                menu.appendChild(menuLink);
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Example JSON

```
{
"id": 22,
"name": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0438 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u0440\u0443\u043f\u0446\u0438\u044f",
"title": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0438 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u0440\u0443\u043f\u0446\u0438\u044f",
"url": "politican",
"order_list": 0,
"meta_title": "\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0440\u0443\u043f\u0446\u0438\u044f",
"meta_desc": null,
"childrens": [
  {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "\u041a\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e",
    "title": "\u041a\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e",
    "url": "medic",
    "order_list": 7,
    "meta_title": null,
    "meta_desc": null,
    "childrens": []
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "name": "\u0414\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e",
    "title": "\u0414\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e",
    "url": "building",
    "order_list": 8,
    "meta_title": null,
    "meta_desc": null,
    "childrens": []
  }
]
},
```

Comment: you already appear to have some code for appending subcategories. Is there a problem you're experiencing? Please explain what actual issue you are facing in your code. Your post so far is a bit too vague. Thankyou.

Comment: @ADyson In json there are 2 children, but when I display them, they are all added to one link
I want that if the object has children, each receives its own link and is displayed

Comment: Untested but pretty sure this is the case: 1) change `menuLink = document.createElement('a');
                menuLink.className = 'menu__link';` to `var menuLink = document.createElement('a');
                menuLink.className = 'menu__link';` (added var to the start) 2. Then move those two lines inside the foreach loop which follows it. That way you create a new menuLink for each child item. Right now you only create one link, no matter how many children there are. It's just a simple logic error, I think.

Comment: @ADyson tnx , its worked 
can you give some advice on how to make this code more universal? do this task for the first time

Comment: well that's a bit tricky to answer. Universal in what way? What scenarios are you envisaging? What functionality do you want to support? There's no magic bullet "universal" answer, there are always constraints etc.

Comment: @ADyson For example, how to make my code more clean, as it seems to me that this is not a very good execution

Comment: it's not too bad really, it's fairly clear, well-formatted, meaningful variable names etc. There are no massive inefficiencies. You could perhaps do something clever using recursion if you wanted to have infinite levels of sub-menus, but I don't know if you need that. What don't you like about your code, specifically? BTW if you want someone to thoroughly review your (otherwise working) code for quality etc, there is a site specifically for  that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - you may want to see if you can ask a suitable question on there.

Comment: @ADyson good idea with endless submenus, now try to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you only create one link, no matter how many children there are. It's just a simple logic error. To fix it:

1. change `menuLink = document.createElement('a'); menuLink.className = 'menu__link';` to `var menuLink = document.createElement('a'); menuLink.className = 'menu__link';` (added var to the start)
2. Then move those two lines inside the foreach loop which follows it.

That way you create a new menuLink for each child item.

Snippet:

```
        let i = elem.childrens,
        menu = document.querySelector('.menu'),

        i.forEach((elem) => {
            console.log('sub-menu-link -' + elem.title);

            var menuLink = document.createElement('a');
            menuLink.className = 'menu__link';
            menuLink.setAttribute('href', '/' + elem.url);
            menuLink.append(elem.name);
            menu.appendChild(menuLink);
        });
```